# pyqt5でQThreadを使って計算中にプログレスバーを動かしたい

Tags: python, pyqt5

pyqt5でQThreadを使って、計算を実行してる最中にプログレスバーを動かしたいです。コードでは左側のプロットをした後、３秒置いて右側のキャンバスにプロットしています。それに伴い、プログレスバーが0%から50%、100%へと変化するようにしたいです。しかし、実際には2つのキャンバスの記述が終わった後に、プログレスバーが一気に100%まで動きます。どのように書き直せばプログレスバーが計算と並行して動作するようになるのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time


class External(QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(External, self).__init__(parent)
        self.win=parent

    def run(self):
        #count_v=0
        count_v=self.win.v
        while count_v < 100:
            count_v=self.win.v
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.countChanged.emit(count_v)     
            #print(count_v)

        self.finished.emit()


class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.v=0
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6),dpi=100)        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.axes = Axes3D(self.figure)
        self.axes.dist=12

        self.figure2 = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6),dpi=100)        
        self.canvas2 = FigureCanvas(self.figure2)
        self.axes2 = Axes3D(self.figure2)
        self.axes2.dist=12
        
        self.button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        #self.plot()       
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas2)

        layout2=QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addLayout(layout)
        layout2.addWidget(self.button)
        layout2.addWidget(self.progress)
        self.setLayout(layout2)

        self.show()

    def plot(self):
        self.calc = External(self)
        self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
        #self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.progress.setValue)
        self.calc.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.calc.start()
        
        self.v=10
        self.plot1()
        self.v=50
        self.plot2()
        time.sleep(3)
        self.v=100
        
    def plot1(self):
        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)
        
        self.axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes.set_zlabel("z")
        
        self.canvas.draw()

    def plot2(self):
        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-6, 6, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)
        
        self.axes2.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
        self.axes2.set_xlabel("x")
        self.axes2.set_ylabel("y")
        self.axes2.set_zlabel("z")
        
        self.canvas2.draw()
        
    def onCountChanged(self, value):
        self.progress.setValue(value)
        #print(value)
       
    def onFinished(self):
        self.progress.setValue(0)
        print("finished")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main thread(Qt の application loop) で `time.sleep()` を実行すると main thread が停止してしまいますので、signal を受け取っても `onCountChanged()` や Qt widget の更新が実行されなくなります。そこで `time.sleep()` の代わりに [QTest.qwait()](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qttest/qtest.html?highlight=qwait#qWait) を使う方法はどうでしょうか。

※ 現時点(2020/11/15)で `QTest` モジュールのドキュメント全般が `TODO` 状態なので判りづらいかと思いますが。。。

変更点だけ記載します。

```py
from PyQt5.QtTest import *  # import QtTest
          :

class Main(QDialog):
          :

    def plot(self):
          :        

        self.v=10
        self.plot1()
        self.v=50
        QTest.qWait(3000) # add qWait()
        self.plot2()
        #time.sleep(3)
        self.v=100
          :        

    def onFinished(self):
        self.progress.setValue(100) # 100%, not 0%
        #self.progress.setValue(0)
        print("finished")
```

Comment: お陰様で無事動作させることが出来ました。ありがとうございました。